# Jenkins legacy token is null and cannot be deleted

Tags: jenkins

After upgrading Jenkins to 2.129 I was warned that 'There are users who are still using a legacy API token.'  I clicked on "see list of impacted users", and after some experimenting with my own login, chose "All" and revoked all of the tokens.  During a screen refresh, the operation aborted and the top token has a userid of 'null'.  I was able to remove the remaining tokens, but the token that is null cannot be revoked.

Is there a way to clean this up?

The log shows:

```
[![Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty$1 in file:/D:/Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.129.jar; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/

Jun 27, 2018 7:43:18 AM WARNING org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context log
Error while serving http://160.207.178.138/administrativeMonitor/legacyApiToken/revokeAllSelected
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jenkins.model.IdStrategy$CaseInsensitive.legacyFilenameOf(IdStrategy.java:260)
    at hudson.model.User.getUnsanitizedLegacyConfigFileFor(User.java:794)
    at hudson.model.User.getOrCreate(User.java:479)
    at hudson.model.User.getById(User.java:636)
    at jenkins.security.apitoken.LegacyApiTokenAdministrativeMonitor.doRevokeAllSelected(LegacyApiTokenAdministrativeMonitor.java:164)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:347)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at net.bull.javamelody.PluginMonitoringFilter.doFilter(PluginMonitoringFilter.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.monitoring.HudsonMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HudsonMonitoringFilter.java:114)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:59)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService.lambda$scheduleNext$0(BoundedExecutorService.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]
```

[image]

Comment: We have rolled Jenkins back for other reasons, so if someone answers I will not be able to confirm a solution...